# Laravel validation translate (german)

Tags: laravel

I have this validation rule

```
'event_start' => 'required|date|after:today',
```

and i can't find where to translate the word "today".

When i hit the validation rule i get this message:

```
Eventstart muss ein Datum nach dem today sein.
```

I have german locale and this is the validation translation

```
'after' => ':attribute muss ein Datum nach dem :date sein.',
```

and i can't find where to edit the word today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `FormRequest` class, you can add the `messages` method to it like this:

```
public function messages() 
{
  return [
    'event_start.after' => 'Eventstart muss ein Datum nach dem today sein.'
  ];
}
```

Or add the:

```
'custom' => [
  'event_start' => [
    'after' => 'Eventstart muss ein Datum nach dem today sein.'
  ]
],
```

to the `validation.php` file.

Im pretty sure, that you can't just translate the `:date`.

Comment: yeah i could do that...but still i am wondering where does this word today come from and how does laravel know that it is really today? there must be a conversion somewhere...

Comment: Because Laravel's Validation class behind the scenes uses PHP's `strtotime` function to parse the date, and that function is capable of reading dates as string, such as `today`, `yesterday`, `tomorrow` and etc. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php